# AWS Cloudfront behaviors not working as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a PHP app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, I have created an assets bucket on S3. I'm trying to setup a Cloudfront distribution with behaviors to send requests for assets/* to S3 with a default behavior to send requests to EB.  The domain points to Cloudfront.

All requests are going to EB which returns a 404 since there is no assets diretory in the EB environment.

I have created 2 Cloudfront origins, one for EB and one for the S3 bucket. This is what my behaviors look like:

```
Precedence  Path Pattern  Origin                                          Protocol Policy   Fwd Query Strings
0           assets/*      S3-example-bucket                               HTTP and HTTPS    No
1           Default (*)   Custom-example.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com   HTTP and HTTPS    Yes
```

It seems as though this should be pretty straight forward so I assume I'm missing something basic.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

Request header:

```
GET /assets/images/10waysaudiobook.png HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: wordpress_logged_in_8a27500b7747be1e4fbad7f473f238e5=snickerspixy%7C1466021823%7Cr7rE5moINjanjHEqb1TGbsSkn9F7OCZLfX69IbcnGJu%7C28fc452885f3fe6e954243abab585a188f6511cdd6eeec6fa5ec5c50b9f3d393; wp-settings-7674=m4%3Do%26m5%3Do%26m9%3Do%26m6%3Do%26editor%3Dhtml%26m10%3Do%26m0%3Do%26m3%3Do%26hidetb%3D1%26m2%3Dc%26m1%3Do%26m8%3Do%26m12%3Do%26m7%3Do%26m11%3Do%26urlbutton%3Dnone%26m13%3Do%26tml1%3D1%26imgsize%3Dfull%26align%3Dcenter%26libraryContent%3Dbrowse%26ed_size%3D569%26unfold%3D1%26wplink%3D1%26mfold%3Do%26post_dfw%3Doff%26advImgDetails%3Dshow%26posts_list_mode%3Dlist; wp-settings-time-7674=1464816549; AWSELB=1FCB85F51606EBAFF15FEADB01C8069AEDE17E2A043407E615EF1A0E1ABF24607545A45D3DC206631F7AAE4503ADA423788B5E6B5B48FAE93EE916DE068509E64F92AC10FF; PHPSESSID=cpi2su7s967phu87rlpjgneel6; wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check
Connection: keep-alive
```

Response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sun, 05 Jun 2016 00:54:23 GMT
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Link: <http://example.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: The configuration seems to be correct for the behavior you described.  The leading slash isn't required by CloudFront (`assets/*` is equivalent to `/assets/*`), so that shouldn't be it.  Consider posting the request and response headers for one of the requests for something in `assets/*` that isn't working as expected.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot added header data. I didn't see anything useful there other than it shows the 404 being generated by WordPress so I know it's coming from EC.

Comment: Philosophically speaking, the information that is *not present* is what tells the tale: This request didn't go through CloudFront at all -- you would have, at minimum, a `Via:` header, an `X-Cache:` header, and an `X-Amz-Cf-Id:` header if it had.  Verify that your DNS is pointing to CloudFront, then if that's correct, check the response and the TTL see when you `dig` for the site's hostname -- it may have been set unnecessarily high and not have had time to run down yet so that the new value can "propagate," if this is a recent change.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot You got it!  DNS issues are my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response headers indicate that this request wasn't served by CloudFront at all, because there are headers that should be present... but are absent.

CloudFront adds `Via:`, `X-Cache:`, and `x-amz-cf-id:` headers to every response, and sometimes `Age:` (on cache hits and errors) or `Vary:` if you're forwarding the `CloudFront-Is-*-Viewer:` headers to the origin.

The absence of these headers suggest that the DNS for the site hasn't been pointed to CloudFront and may still be pointing directly to the EB environment, or if the change was recent, that the former TTL for the DNS entry may not yet have expired.